# Emacs really laggy on prog-mode

Tags: init-file, debugging, prog-mode, profiler

I noticed Emacs was really laggy on any mode derived from prog-mode two days ago. Before that, everything was fine. I can navigate on a 1000+ lines org-mode file without problem, but I can't even type without lag on a 100- line of a C file, or a 50 lines Haskell file.

I have tried many things. I have disabled several modes to see if anything helps. It seems that disabling evil-mode helps, but doesn't solve it (and bare in mind, I use evil-mode on long org or LaTeX files without any lag).

I have also done the profiler on cpu (and memory, but only posted the cpu), and these are the results:

`cpu:
- command-execute                                               80022  75%
 - call-interactively                                           80022  75%
  - funcall-interactively                                       79047  74%
   - evil-scroll-line-up                                        77417  72%
    - scroll-down                                               76489  71%
     - jit-lock-function                                        76455  71%
      - jit-lock-fontify-now                                    76455  71%
       - apply                                                  76455  71%
        - ad-Advice-jit-lock-fontify-now                        76455  71%
         - #<compiled 0x267e7d>                                 76455  71%
          - jit-lock--run-functions                             76451  71%
           - run-hook-wrapped                                   76451  71%
            - #<compiled 0xef9bd7>                              76451  71%
             - highlight-indent-guides--guide-region            39739  37%
              - font-lock-fontify-region                        39674  37%
               - font-lock-default-fontify-region               39671  37%
                - font-lock-fontify-keywords-region             39645  37%
                 - eval                                         39636  37%
                  - if                                          39636  37%
                   - or                                         35672  33%
                    - elt                                       35672  33%
                       syntax-ppss                              35140  33%
                   + when                                        3402   3%
                   + parse-partial-sexp                           559   0%
                + font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region           11   0%
                + font-lock-unfontify-region                        4   0%
                syntax-ppss                                        48   0%
              + highlight-indent-guides--get-prev-guides           11   0%
              + highlight-indent-guides--guide-line                 3   0%
             - font-lock-fontify-region                         36708  34%
              - font-lock-default-fontify-region                36708  34%
               - font-lock-fontify-keywords-region              36692  34%
                - eval                                          36679  34%
                 - if                                           36673  34%
                  - or                                          36666  34%
                   - elt                                        36666  34%
                      syntax-ppss                               36660  34%
                  + parse-partial-sexp                              7   0%
               + font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region             7   0%
               + font-lock-unfontify-region                         3   0%
             + nlinum--region                                       4   0%
          + run-with-timer                                          4   0%
     + eval                                                        34   0%`

The modes I have on are:

- Async-Bytecomp-Package
- Auto-Compile-On-Load
- Auto-Fill
- Column-Number
- Diff-Auto-Refine
- Evil
- Evil-Commentary
- Evil-Leader
- Evil-Local
- Evil-Surround
- File-Name-Shadow
- Flyspell
- Global-Evil-Surround
- Global-Git-Commit
- Global-Nlinum-Relative
- Global-Undo-Tree
- Global-Yascroll-Bar
- Haskell-Indentation
- Helm
- Highlight-Indent-Guides
- Magit-Auto-Revert
- Nlinum
- Nlinum-Relative
- Override-Global
- Projectile
- Savehist
- Shell-Dirtrack
- Show-Paren
- Smart-Cursor-Color
- Tex-Pdf
- Undo-Tree
- Yas-Global
- Yascroll-Bar

If any more information is needed, I'll gladly provide, I don't know how to debug this very well.

Comment: Start emacs without your init file (emacs -Q). Then recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the problem.

Comment: Using the profiler is correct (and you can probably stick to the CPU profiler), but you haven't examined the results in enough detail.  Don't worry about quoting the negligible impact items (e.g. anything showing "0%" CPU is clearly not a problem), but you *do* need to keep drilling down into those `evil-scroll-line-up` and `evil-next-line` items, until you have produced all of the data for those.

Comment: What @Dan said. You really need to remove everything that is not directly relevant to the question from your question. After doing that, provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post to be a bit more specific on the problem. My init file is quite extensive, and I'm using `org-mode` to manage it (I'll link the `init.el` file from my github), but I don't think I understand what @Drew said about the "step-by-step to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`". Here's my [emacs setup](https://github.com/heartb1t/emacs-dot).

Comment: This is the point: Instead of tossing your whole init file at us, bisect it to find out just what the problem is. Then ask a specific question about that part of it, if you still need to. It's likely that most (maybe 95%) of your init file is irrelevant to the problem you are trying to ask about. It's your job to pare that down, in order to help others help you better.

Comment: Oh, okay. Since Dan's comment I've been trying to load my emacs without the init file and load snippets of code separately to figure out if anything helps. The problem seems to be centered around `nlinum` and `highlight-indent-guides`. I've already disabled `highlight-indent-guides` and that improved my performance a little bit, and I've also set `nlinum` to only update every 0.2 seconds, but I still get a bit of lag, and I need `nlinum-relative` a lot, since I use a lot of vim motions that depend on a number of lines, like `16 d j` that delets 16 lines down.